# Edd./ed. for @book entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, thesis, bibliographystyle, biblatex-philosophy

I'm doing my thesis and I've a question: how can I print "ed./edd." only for @book entry and "edited by" for @collection?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
        
            \usepackage[%
            bibstyle=philosophy-verbose,%
            citestyle=authoryear,%
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber,%
            classical = true,%
            scauthors = bibcite,%
            dashed = true,%trattino al posto del nome dell'autore nelle entrate multiple
            volnumformat = parens,%
            volumeformat = Roman,%
            firstinits=true,%
            volnumformat=strings,%
            volumeformat=romansc,%
            sorting=nyt,%
            relatedformat=brackets,%
            editionformat=superscript,
            indexing]{biblatex}
        
            \usepackage{polyglossia} 
            \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
            \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english}
            \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
            \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}
        
            \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
        
        \renewcommand*{\editorstrgdelim}{\addcomma\space}%TOGLIERE PARENTESI ALLE DICITURE IN BIBLIO
        \DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{#1}
        
        \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %carattere strano autori in bibliografi
        
        \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
        byeditor = {{a cura di}},
        editor = {{ed\adddot}},
        editors = {{edd\adddot}},
        translator = {{trad\adddot}},
        translators = {{tradd\adddot}},
        phdthesis = {{ }},
        }
        
        \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%edd. quando ci sono più editori
          \ifnameundef{editor}
            {}
            {\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
             \clearname{editor}%
             \newunit}%
          \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
          \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
        
        \renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%edd. quando ci sono più traduttori
          \ifnameundef{translator}
            {}
            {\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
             \clearname{translator}%
             \newunit}%
          \usebibmacro{bytranslator}}%
        
        \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[%book,
        article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}%PER FAR SPARIRE VOL. VOLL.
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
        %\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{{} -- {}}
        %\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{{} -- {}} %mettere trattino a fine elenco autori o editori in biblio
    
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[%book,
    article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}%PER FAR SPARIRE VOL. VOLL.
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    
    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
      \printtext{%  invece di \printtext[pureparens]{%
        \iffieldundef{issue}
          {\usebibmacro{date}}
          {\printfield{issue}%
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{date}}}%
      \newunit}
    
    \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
      \usebibmacro{journal}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \iffieldundef{series}
        {}%
        {\newunit%
         \printfield{series}\setunit{\addspace}\midsentence}%
         \newunit%
      \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%  invece di \setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
      \usebibmacro{issue}%
      \newunit}
    
    \renewbibmacro*{title+issuetitle}{%
      \usebibmacro{periodical}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \iffieldundef{series}
        {}%
        {\newunit
         \printfield{series}%
         \setunit{\addspace}\midsentence}%
      \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%  invece di \setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
      \usebibmacro{issue}%
      \newunit}
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %METTERE VOL DOPO TITOLO NEI LIBRI----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
      \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
      \usebibmacro{begentry}%
      \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
      \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
      \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
        \newunit
      \iffieldundef{maintitle}
        {\printfield{volume}%
         \printfield{part}}
        {}%
      \newunit
      \printlist{language}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{edition}%
      \newunit
      \printfield{volumes}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
      \newunit
      \printfield{pagetotal}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
        {\printfield{isbn}}
        {}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
      \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}\newblock
      \iftoggle{bbx:related}
        {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
         \usebibmacro{related}}
        {}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{pageref}%
      \newblock\nopunct%
        \usebibmacro{series+number}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{finentry}}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{.} %punto a fine entrata bibliografica

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@collection{fragmenta,
keywords = {libro},
editor = {H. Hofman and Annette Harder},
title = {Fragmenta dramatica},
subtitle = {Belträge zur Interpretation der griechischen Tragikerfragmente und ihrer Wirkungsgeschichte},
address = {Göttingen},
year = {1991}
}

@incollection{harder1991,
keywords = {libro},
author = {Annette Harder},
title = {Euripides’ \emph{Temenos} and \emph{Temenidai}},
Crossref = {fragmenta},
pages = {117--135},
shorthand = {Harder 1991}
}

@book{kannicht2004,
keywords = {libro},
title = {Tragicorum Graecorum Fragmenta},
volume = {V.2},
editor = {Richard Kannicht},
address = {Göttingen},
year = {2004},
shorthand = {Kannicht 2004},
options = {useeditor=false}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

What I want is something like this:[image]
but this MWE prints this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to tweak your version of the macro `byeditor+others`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
          \ifnameundef{editor}
            {}
            {\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
             \clearname{editor}%
             \newunit}%
          \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
          \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
```

to include a conditional that checks the entry type and prints the bibstring "byeditor" **iff** the type is `@book`:

```
\ifentrytype{book}{\usebibmacro{byeditor}}{<otherwise proceed as before>}
```

Here a truly [**minimal**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) example (whereas yours ended up being quite `philosophy-verbose` if you'll allow me a pun):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
byeditor = {{a cura di}},
editor = {{ed\adddot}},
editors = {{edd\adddot}},
}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
\ifnameundef{editor}
{}
{%
\ifentrytype{book}{\usebibmacro{byeditor}}{%  % this line is new ...
\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%       % (this part stays the same)
\setunit{\addspace}%
\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
\clearname{editor}%
\newunit}}%                        % ...the 2nd closing brace is new
\usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
\usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@collection{fragmenta,
keywords = {libro},
editor = {H. Hofman and Annette Harder},
title = {Fragmenta dramatica},
subtitle = {Belträge zur Interpretation der griechischen Tragikerfragmente und ihrer Wirkungsgeschichte},
address = {Göttingen},
year = {1991}
}

@incollection{harder1991,
keywords = {libro},
author = {Annette Harder},
title = {Euripides’ \emph{Temenos} and \emph{Temenidai}},
Crossref = {fragmenta},
pages = {117--135},
shorthand = {Harder 1991}
}

@book{kannicht2004,
keywords = {libro},
title = {Tragicorum Graecorum Fragmenta},
volume = {V.2},
editor = {Richard Kannicht},
address = {Göttingen},
year = {2004},
shorthand = {Kannicht 2004},
options = {useeditor=false}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So many thanks! :)

Comment: With pleasure :)